# Access a parent class variable in its child in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, scope, widget

I am trying to use a custom statefull PageWrapper widget to wrap all my pages. The idea is to make it return a Scaffold and use the same menu drawer and bottom navigation bar, and call the appropriate page as page parameter.

My bottomNavigationBar is working well and I am setting the correct selectedIndex, but I can't find a way to access it in the child page (that is in another file), since I don't know how to access the parent's selectedIndex and display the appropriate widget from my page's list.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageWrapper extends StatefulWidget {

  final Widget page;
  final AppBar appBar;
  final BottomNavigationBar bottomNav;
  final Color bckColor;

  PageWrapper({@required this.page, this.appBar, this.bckColor, this.bottomNav});

  @override
  _PageWrapperState createState() => _PageWrapperState();
}

class _PageWrapperState extends State<PageWrapper> {

  int _selectedIndex;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedIndex = 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: widget.appBar,
        backgroundColor: widget.bckColor,
        bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavigation(selectedIndex: _selectedIndex, onItemTapped: _onItemTapped),
        body: widget.page,
        drawer: Drawer(...),
    );
  }
}
```

Named roots in my main.dart:

```
home: PageWrapper(page: HomeScreen()),
routes: {
  'form': (context) => PageWrapper(page: RoomService()),
},
```

I would like to access that bottom navigation bar's current index somehow in my HomeScreen and RoomService screen. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve that by using a State Management tool like `Provider` or `Bloc`. To keep things simple, lets use [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to do it.

Wrap `MaterialApp` with a `ChangeNotifierProvider` in your main.dart.

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<IndexModel>(
        create: (context) => IndexModel()),
  ],
  child: MaterialApp(...)
);
```

Create a model that will hold your index value:
Also, you have to override the getter and setter of index in order to call `notifyListeners` after its value is set. Here is an example:

```
class IndexModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _index;
  get index => _index;
  set index(int index) {
    _index = index;
    notifyListeners(); //Notifies its listeners that the value has changed
  }
}
```

Here is how you can display your data according to its index (Ideally, you should use Selector instead of Consumer so that the widget only rebuilds if the value it is listening to, changes):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 //other widgets
 Selector<IndexModel, String>(
  selector: (_, model) => model.index,
  builder: (_, i, __) {
   switch(i){
     //do your returning here based on the index
      }
     },
   );
  }
 )
}
```

Extra note. Here is how you can access the values of ImageModel in your UI:

```
final model=Provider.of<IndexModel>(context,listen:false);
int index =model.index; //get index value
model.index=index; //set your index value
```

You have to pass `listen:false` when you aren't listening for changes. This is needed when you are accessing it in `initState` or in `onPressed`.

Comment: I've been trying to avoid provider, but it all works perfectly!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Good luck in your project.